# Particular Integral of a Homogenous Linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Consider, $z$ a function of $z= f(x,y)$ and D & D' respectively represent partial differential operators, i.e $$\frac{∂}{∂}, \quad\frac{∂}{∂y}$$
[image: .]
i am learning particular integrals for PDE using the expansion method but unable to understand the marked expansions used in the image. can someone help with this?

Comment: @Gonçalo yes i understood that, i was not able to follow along where the author uses the $$\frac{D}{D'} (x+y)  = y$$
To be specific, $$\frac{1}{2D'^{2}}[1-\frac{3}{2} \frac{D}{D'}+....](x+y)= \frac{1}{2D'^{2}}[x+y -\frac{3}{2}y] $$

Comment: wow, thanks for explaining it so thoroughly. Its simple, somehow i wasn't able to visualise it.